# How to find the inverse of the function

Tags: functions, inverse

Consider the function $g(x) = x^2 - 2x+3$ on the domain $D = (1,3)$.

Determine a suitable codomain $C$ so that the function has an inverse function and find the inverse function.

I've already found the codomain but I'm struggling to find the inverse. Do I have to complete the square? I have no idea how I'm supposed to do it with this sort of question. Am I completely wrong? Should I be trying to apply some other formula?

Comment: Completing the square is indeed a quick way.
$$
y = x^2 - 2x +3 = x^2 -2x +1 +2 =(x-1)^2 + 2 \Rightarrow (x-1)^2 = y -2  
$$
etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let use quadratic formula.

$$y= x^2 - 2x+3 \implies x^2 - 2x+3-y=0\implies x=...$$

or as an alternative

$$y= x^2 - 2x+3 =(x-1)^2+2\implies (x-1)^2=y-2 \implies x=...$$